# why does os.startfile not open up requested file

Tags: python

Hi can anyone help me set up a task . I want to automate a task to open an app at a specific time but for now i'm just trying to open an app with my code but when i try to run it in vscode i have to type the file name into the terminal for it to open .

```
def openFile():
    try:
        os.startfile(r"C:\Users\user\Documents>hi.txt")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: Could you run us through the steps taken on vscode?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that it was running too fast
I added a time function and it's running perfectly now

```
while os.startfile(r"C:\Users\user\Documents\hi.txt"):
   print("I'm going to wait 5 seconds now!")
   time.sleep(5)
```